# Visual Studio Not Allowing Vector in Struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, struct

I'm trying to include a vector in a struct.  Here is my relevant code:

```
typedef struct {
    __int64 s;
    __int64 c;
    __int64 h = 0; 
    __int64 i = 0;
    __int64 s_h;
    __int64 n_ss;
    __int64 n_ss_hh;
    __int64 min_hh = 0;
    __int64 min_cc;
    bool drawn = false;
} CardInfoEx;

typedef struct {
    __int64 ss;
    __int64 cc;
    __int64 hh;
    __int64 n_ss;
    ULONG_PTR count;
    ULONG_PTR mcount;
    vector<CardInfoEx> cards;
} DrawInfoEx;
```

Visual Studio gives me an error C2143 "syntax error: missing ';' before '<'" when I try to compile this.  I saw another post on this forum saying this was perfectly valid.  Is the above actually valid?

Comment: No, the above is not valid. Whatever this "vector" is, it's not defined, hence your compiler's complaint. Perhaps you meant to `#include <vector>` beforehand, and then declare a `std::vector` class member?

Comment: Also, there is no need for `typedef struct` in a C++ program.  All you need is `struct CardInfoEx;` for example.  Second, hopefully your codebase that uses these `structs` do not do something destructive like `memset` or `memcpy` to or from instances of these structs.  If so, your program has undefined behavior (I have seen that type of coding before, where the coder still believes they're dealing with `C` structs, and erroneously uses `C` functions on them).